# DVD Playback support on Windows 8

Tags: wpf, windows-8

What are the possible options for implementing DVD playback for windows 8? DirectShow does not seems to be working now as Microsoft has removed support for DVD playback. Am I right about it? I am using WPF and DirectShow.NET for Windows 7.

Comment: Why you think DirectShow is not working? jsut  because MS removed the codecs? Well, buy some.

Comment: TomTom : That's an option but we need to implement it as an independent feature without requirement of buying new codecs and I am looking for possible options.

Comment: Ah, REALITY CHECK: You NEED A CODEC to decode. It MUST be paid - because it contains licensed code. Microsoft does not deliver one anymore (it was in Win 7). How you plan magically not having a codec? It that is a requirement, whoever wrote the requirement is an idiot. Point. You NEED a coded. Even if you write it yourself, you have to pay license fees for it.

Comment: TomTom : Thanks, I got it. So I can still use DirectShow All I have to do is to buy a suitable codec. The bad thing is that it will add extra cost to our product.

Comment: Yes. MS just removed the codecs. Even with media center they are now coded not be usable outside media center. And you will need a codec legally anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VLC player is free and works fine on non-ARM Windows 8 (i.e. won't work for WindowsRT). You can grab a copy here:

http://www.vlcapp.com/jump/vlc-free/

Does a great job of playing DVDs.

Comment: Jeremy, Thanks for looking. We were supporting DVD playback in our application using DirectShow till Windows 7, VLC player can be used to play DVDs as an independent player, but can I use it somehow in my application. I have been looking for some free library and even VLC API which allows DVD playback but could not find one. Can you suggest something?